# Ember-data wont "Join" related models

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

When I specify a a hasMany relation using the FixtureAdapter, the players array for each team won't be populated unless I specify an array of id's for the player like so

```
App.Team.FIXTURES = [
  {id: 1, name: 'The Swagkings', players: [1,2,3,4]}
]
```

When the Team is setup like so

```
App.Team.FIXTURES = [
  {id: 3, name: 'The Mississauga Bears'}
]
```

Then the teams player array isn't automatically populated.
Furthermore, the reverse relationship isn't set up (IE player's team isn't populated)

I have a sample app I wrote here to illustrate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/edude03/qCdAY/

While I can make it work by specifying the player IDs I feel like this is the wrong way to do it, especially considering that's not how the data is returned from the backend.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Your link is erroring for me?

Comment: Not sure why, but I updated the link anyway. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a limitation of Ember Data. Specifically, **at present**, bidirectional links are not set up on data returned from the adapter at load time.

This is a very short-term limitation that we expect to have fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, is there a workaround for this at the moment though?

Comment: The main workaround is to provide the relationships in the JSON from both the parent and child side. That is easy enough in fixtures, but maybe not from your server.

Comment: Is this still the case? (It seems to be for me with 1.0.0) Where might we learn more or follow along?